# h:commandButton is not working - action

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I am making an application using jsf and I have a problem when sending data from one of the rows of the datatable to a bean and then redirect to another page. Just to state, I'm using bootsfaces. Here are the codes:

JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"    
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <ui:define name="title">Home</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <b:dataTable value="#{LeiloesMB.lista()}" var="l">
            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Leilao"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.leilao.id}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Encerramento"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.leilao.encerramento}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Item"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.item.nome}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Descrição"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.item.descricao}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Maior Lance"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.valor}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="ID"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{l.usuario.id}"/>
            </b:column>

            <b:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{l.usuario.nome}"/>
            </b:column>            

            <b:column rendered="#{not empty Usuario.user.nome}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Realizar Lance"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton value="Faça seu lance" action="#{LanceMB.lance(Usuario.user, l)}"/>
                </h:form>
            </b:column>

        </b:dataTable>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

LanceMB code:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="LanceMB")
public class NovoLance {
    private Usuario user = new Usuario();
    private LancesLeilao ll = new LancesLeilao();
    private double novo_valor;


    public String lance(Usuario usuario, LancesLeilao lal){
        this.user = usuario;
        this.ll = lal;
        return "novolance";            
    }

    //getters.. setters
   }
```

Usuario code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="Usuario")
@SessionScoped
public class UserSession {
    private String email, senha;
    private Usuario user = new Usuario();

//getters and setters..
}
```

Any question leave a comment.

Comment: Is there another form at outside of datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<h:commandButton />` is used to push the values of individual fields in a form to the managed bean defined. I see that you have enclosed just the button within the form but not the values themselves.

Wrap all the values within the form including the button and give it a try. It should work if everything else has been defined correctly.

Hope this helps :)